# Quantum relative entropy between states

Tags: quantum-information

Let $\sigma$ be a quantum state and $\Pi$ be a projector onto a subspace. Consider the state $\rho=\Pi\sigma\Pi$ and $\mathrm{tr}(\rho)=p<1$. Can we say anything about their quantum relative entropy $S(\rho||\sigma)$, e.g., it is positive or negative?

It does not seem clear $S(\rho||\sigma)\geq 0$ since $\rho$ is now subnormalized. Also the triangle inequality does not hold for quantum relative entropy so not sure if I may consider any intermediate state.